# Open Street Map long line disappears at high zoom level

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I'm working on a pathcreator with osm. Adding lines works fine, but when one makes a very long line and zooms in on it, the line disappears at a high zoom level. It seems that this appears if the viewport is to far away from the start and/or end point of the line. Maybe splitting the line could help, but which is the max size for this?

here is a minified code sample, if you zoom in to level 7 the line is gone:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {    
            var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');

            var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Mapnik("Mapnik");
            map.addLayer(mapnik);

            var path = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("path");
            map.addLayer(path);  

            var pathStyle = {
                    strokeColor: "#0033ff",
                    strokeOpacity: 0.7,
                    strokeWidth: 5
            };

            var points = new Array(
                    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-7856503.5146562, 880554.5664875),
                    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(8502243.5278938, 724011.5325875)
            );

            var line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points);

            var lineFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(line, null, pathStyle);
            path.addFeatures([lineFeature]);

            map.zoomToExtent(path.getDataExtent());
    });
```

i'm quite new to osm so maybe im just messing up something.. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was playing around with firebug and going through the svg elements. It turned out that osm uses svg polyline for making lines. The values of the line are running out of space with values over 15000 which is to much for there renderer.

I checked in a bug report on this issue:
https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/617

My current workaround is to split the line into 100 km peaces. This works but takes more calculations.

if someone is intressted here is a site with helpful math:
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html